# How does an Orleans application benefit from containers?

Tags: c#, docker, docker-swarm, orleans

The Microsoft Orleans framework provides a way of building distributed, high-scale systems without much complexity.

Scaling is natural for Orleans; if a host goes down, the active grains that were on that host get re-activated elsewhere since their state is persisted in storage.

With this in mind, how do container services like Docker apply to an Orleans application in production? If Orleans already scales by default, why do we need an orchestrated container service to do the scaling?

Answer (score 6):

Re-activation of grains upon host failure is not scaling - it is application reliability (auto-healing).

Scaling applies to an ability to add more servers and the application automatically adjusting itself to use this extra hardware.
Orleans provides the application auto-scaling: if you add more servers, Orleans will automatically start using those servers by putting new grains on the new servers.
But someone still needs to decide to add more servers. Orleans does not do it automatically. There must be some (external to Orleans) control loop that will measure CPU or throughput or some other metric and decide to add more servers.
Container cluster orchestrations can do that.

Another benefit of containers is easier management - it is easier to "lift and shift" the whole container with all the SW inside it to another Cloud provider or on-prem than the SW directly, because containers can capture all SW dependencies. This is totally unrelated to Orleans and is just a general benefit of containers.